# What is the best practise to run long runnig calculations with OpenCPU?

Tags: opencpu

Hi I want to use the power and flexibility of OpenCPU to start long runnig calculations (several minutes or so). I am facing issues where OpenCPU terminates processing of given scripts. I have modified `/etc/opencpu/server.conf` option `timelimit.post` to 600 (seconds) but it seems that is not taking an effect. Is there any other cofig file that must be modified in order to increase timeouts?

Or more generally - what is the best practise to run long running calculations with OpenCPU?

Comment: Editing `timelimit.post` should work. Which version of opencpu are you running? Did you restart the server afterwards? Which version of opencpu are you running?

Comment: Just curious, does opencpu's `timelimit.post` trump apache's `Timeout`? In my (ubuntu) install in apache2.conf, it lists the default timeout as 300.